# Mudflap unreasonably reporting memory access violation

Tags: c++, debugging

When using mudflap to debug my program, it reports this error:

```
*******
mudflap violation 1 (unregister): time=1365083992.573241 ptr=0x20ce510 size=0
pc=0x7f745259d5f6
Nearby object 1: checked region begins 257B after and ends 257B after
mudflap object 0x20ce440: name=`malloc region'
bounds=[0x20cc4d0,0x20ce40f] size=8000 area=heap check=0r/0w liveness=0
alloc time=1365083992.572980 pc=0x7f745259da51
      /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/libmudflap.so.0(__mf_register+0x41) [0x7f745259da51]
      /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/libmudflap.so.0(__wrap_malloc+0xe2) [0x7f745259e752]
      /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/libstdc++.so.6(_Znwm+0x1d) [0x7f7452348f9d]
      /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/libstdc++.so.6(_Znam+0x9) [0x7f74523490b9]
number of nearby objects: 1
Neoprávněný přístup do paměti (SIGSEGV)
```

After bit of testing, it seems that

```
int *a[ 1000 ];
```

Is legal, while

```
int ** a = new int * [ 1000 ];
```

in not legal according to Mudflap and generates the above error.

What is the difference, if any, between the first and the second example?

Comment: I can explain the difference but I can't explain the error.

Comment: @sftrabbit please go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *a[ 1000 ];
```

This is a declaration. It declares an array of 1000 pointers to `int`. Think of it like 1000 little boxes and inside each one you can place an `int*`.

```
int ** a = new int * [ 1000 ];
```

This is a declaration. It declares a pointer to pointer to `int`, nothing more. It's just a single little box and inside it you can place an `int**`.

However, it just so happens that you are initialising the value of this `int**` with the result of a *new-expression*: `new int * [ 1000 ]`. This dynamically allocates an array of 1000 pointers to int and then gives you a pointer to the first of them. So it gives you an `int**`, which you initialise `a` with.

In the first line, an array of `int*`s was declared and so will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. However, in the second line, just an `int**` was declared and only *that* will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. The array that you dynamically allocated will not be. I imagine that the reason you're getting this violation is because you aren't destroying the dynamically allocated object.

You'll have to do:

```
delete[] a;
```

The rule is that whenever you use `new`/`new[]`, there should be a corresponding `delete`/`delete[]`.